# C program closes without error while trying to read a file?

Tags: c, windows, gtk

I have written a very simple C program with a GTK interface that has allows the user to load an input file.

On some Windows 10 computers, the program crashes without showing any error window while trying to read the input file. But on other computers, it reads files just fine.

Is there a known cause for this kind of inconsistent behavior on Windows?

Comment: You will likely have to use a debugger on a machine where it crashes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't -- the problem has been reported by someone else and I don't have access to their computer. Is there any hope for me with this bug, given that I can't reproduce it? I thought it could be related to Windows defender, but after trying all combinations of file access settings, I still could not generate a crash. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Ask them to send you the dump file so you can debug it.  If it crashes with no message, Windows will usually write a dump out to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps`.  Make sure they zip the file, as it is potentially quite large.  Note also that, since you mentioned reading a file, on Windows systems you need to specify filenames with wide strings.  Otherwise you may have issues dealing with file paths containing certain non-English characters.  And no, UTF-8 will not help you -- it must be UTF-16.  Window is so fun...

Comment: An alternative may be to create a crash [minidump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/minidump-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN). These files are smaller than full crashdumps.

Comment: Thank you paddy, I wasn't aware of these dump files. I will ask the user to send those to me. @AndreasWenzel, are minidumps also generated automatically?

Comment: Yes minidumps are great, but I think the problem here is that the mechanism available for just-in-time crash reporting (or writing a minidump from Task Manager while the program is displaying an exception message dialog) is completely bypassed when Windows kills the app.  This can happen when you hit kernel-level exceptions or encounter driver bugs.

Comment: In the meantime make sure that you checked each and every return code of called functions, especially those working with the input file.

Comment: The user has provided me with his local crash dumps, and none were related to my program. So apparently it crashes without showing an error message and without leaving a crash dump whenever it attempts to read a file. Also, I have just found that it cannot write files. The only antivirus the user has is Windows Defender. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: @bluewhale: Does the function which opens the file (e.g. `fopen` or `CreateFile`) provide a return value which indicates success or failure? If it reports failure, then you can use [`perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) if you used `fopen`, or [`GetLastError`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) if you used `CreateFile`, in order to determine the cause of the error. You can use the same error reporting functions if opening the file succeeds, but reading or writing the file fails (unless `ferror` returns false).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, that was a great suggestion. I have given the user an executable that shows the error in a popup window -- what I am actually using is ifstream to read the file, and I captured the error using strerror(errno). It turns out that the error message is the following: "No such file or directory". This is a bit cryptic, but it's big progress.

Comment: @bluewhale: If you are using `std::istream`, why did you tag the question with the `c` tag instead of the `c++` tag? Please consider changing the tag.

Comment: The fact that `strerror(errno)` gives the "No such file or directory" error message could be a sign that @paddy was correct with their suspicion that the user is maybe using non-7-bit-ASCII characters in their pathname. Are you using UNICODE strings or ASCII strings in your program? Also, in my experience, even when dealing with plain 7-bit-ASCII, spaces in pathnames can sometimes cause trouble.

Comment: I'm indeed using ASCII strings, and I have managed to reproduce the bug by creating a file with japanese characters in its filename and trying to load it. Now I am trying to replace all strings with wstrings in my program, but that's being a bit painful because there doesn't seem to be a simple way of converting between string/char* and wstring/wchar_t*, and also between Gdk's gchar* and wstring/wchar_t*...

Comment: Character conversions are always painful.  It's useful to decide on a standard that you will primarily work with in your program, and then develop robust utility functions around that.  I use UTF-8 for internals, and UTF-16 for any Win32 stuff. See [MultiByteToWideChar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) and [WideCharToMultiByte](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte).  Take care to avoid buffer overruns -- read the docs carefully and use the API result codes wisely.

Comment: I also notice you talk about `string` and `wstring` which sound like you might be using the C++ standard library, despite your question being marked as C language.  If you're actually using C++, then consider using `std::codecvt` from [<locale>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/locale)